# Firefox addon opens tab with content, copy/paste of the tabs url will not load page fully

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have an addon that places an `ActionButton` on the toolbar. When the `ActionButton` is clicked the code below is run.

The code opens a new tab and provides some `html` and `js`, this acts as the addon's UI.

The `url` of the new tab is:

```
resource://jid1-qljswfs6someid-at-jetpack/addon-firefox/data/html/view.html
```

If I copy/paste that `url` into another new tab manually, the `html` displays but the `js` logic is not loaded. Is there a way to do this without clicking the `ActionButton`? So I could maybe bookmark the addon instead of having the `ActionButton` take up space.

Code:

```
Tabs.open({
  url: require("sdk/self").data.url('html/view.html'),
  onReady: function onReady(tab) {

    worker = tab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: [
        require("sdk/self").data.url.get('lib/lib1.js'),
        require("sdk/self").data.url.get('js/lib1.js')
      ],
      onMessage: function(message) {

        console.log('stuff done');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run it whenever the site from `data.url('html/view.html')` is loaded you would have to use [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) instead of manually attaching to the document to the tab.

Your include pattern would be something like `data.url('html/view.html') + "*"`, so it also attaches to the page if there is a hash or a query to the document.

Comment: Awesome help to the firefox addons tags you're giving lately @humanoid keep it up!